# Combine all like values to an array

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, interface, reduce

Here I have an object `Version`

```js
 /** Model **/
 interface Version {
   name: string
   version: number
   someotherproperty: string
   conditional: boolean
 } 

 /** Expected Object Outcome **/
 interface Application {
   name: string
   versions: Version[]
 }

/** Incomplete constant that should return an Application Array. **/
const data = listOfVersions.reduce((a, item) => return Application[])
```

I'm trying to create a function that uses ES6 [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to generate a list of versions by name.

I don't really want to expand on my horrid code below, I want to replace it:

```
for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
  var current = data[j];
  for(var i=j+1;i<data.length;i++){
    if(current.name = data[i].name){
      if(!isArray(current.version))
        current.version = [ current.version ];
      if(isArray(data[i].version))
         for(var v=0;v<data[i].version.length;v++)
           current.version.push(data[i].version[v]);
      else
        current.version.push(data[i].version);
      data.splice(i,1);
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an object indexed by name, containing a version array in its values, then take the object's values:

```
const versionsByName: {[name: string]: Application} = {};
for (const { name, version } of listOfVersions) {
  if (!versionsByName[name]) {
    versionsByName[name] = { name, versions: [] };
  }
  versionsByName[name].versions.push(version);
}
const output = Object.values(versionsByName);
```

While it's *possible* to do the same thing with `reduce`, I don't think it's all that appropriate - it requires more code and is a bit harder to understand at a glance. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) by V8 developers on the subject.